# Flyway not picking up migration file in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, flyway

I've followed a few tutorials and configured Flyway for DB initialisation.

I took a schema dump from MYSQL (no data) and named the file `V1__initialSchema.sql`. So this is full of specific create table, foreign keys etc. as dumped by mysql.

Then I've configured the beans:

Flyway Initiailser

```
@Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
protected Flyway flyway() {
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
    //flyway.setLocations("classpath:db/migration");
    flyway.setDataSource(dataSource());

    return flyway;
}
```

JPA Initialiser

```
@Bean
@DependsOn(value = "flyway")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.ideafactory.mvc", "com.ideafactory.plugins");


    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    //jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","create-drop");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", false);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", false);
    jpaProperties.put("hibnerate.connection.CharSet", "utf8");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.connect.characterEncoding", "utf8");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", true);

    jpaProperties.put("jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes", true);

    factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    factory.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
    return factory;
}
```

I switched on logging and I can see it is "skipping" my initialise file, which I'm not sure why. The schema hasn't been created.

```
l.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Scanning for classpath resources at 'db/migration' (Prefix: 'V', Suffix: '.sql')
16:35:08.272 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Scanning URL: file:/Users//Documents/Projects/MerchantX/target/java_ecommerce/WEB-INF/classes/db/migration/
16:35:08.273 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - JBoss VFS v2 available: false
16:35:08.273 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Scanning starting at classpath root in filesystem: /Users//Documents/Projects/MerchantX/target/java_ecommerce/WEB-INF/classes/
16:35:08.273 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Scanning for resources in path: /Users//Documents/Projects/MerchantX/target/java_ecommerce/WEB-INF/classes/db/migration (db/migration)
16:35:08.273 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Found resource: db/migration/V1__initialSchema.sql
16:35:08.279 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Scanning for classes at 'db/migration' (Implementing: 'org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration')
16:35:08.279 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Scanning URL: file:/Users//Documents/Projects/MerchantX/target/java_ecommerce/WEB-INF/classes/db/migration/
16:35:08.279 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - JBoss VFS v2 available: false
16:35:08.280 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Scanning starting at classpath root in filesystem: /Users//Documents/Projects/MerchantX/target/java_ecommerce/WEB-INF/classes/
16:35:08.280 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Scanning for resources in path: /Users//Documents/Projects/MerchantX/target/java_ecommerce/WEB-INF/classes/db/migration (db/migration)
16:35:08.280 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Filtering out resource: db/migration/V1__initialSchema.sql (filename: V1__initialSchema.sql)
16:35:08.281 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Scanning for classes at 'db/migration' (Implementing: 'org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.spring.SpringJdbcMigration')
16:35:08.281 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Scanning URL: file:/Users//Documents/Projects/MerchantX/target/java_ecommerce/WEB-INF/classes/db/migration/
16:35:08.282 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - JBoss VFS v2 available: false
16:35:08.282 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Scanning starting at classpath root in filesystem: /Users//Documents/Projects/MerchantX/target/java_ecommerce/WEB-INF/classes/
16:35:08.282 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Scanning for resources in path: /Users//Documents/Projects/MerchantX/target/java_ecommerce/WEB-INF/classes/db/migration (db/migration)
16:35:08.282 DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog 40 debug - Filtering out resource: db/migration/V1__initialSchema.sql (filename: V1__initialSchema.sql)
```

I haven't used Flyway before, can anyone explain why it filtered out my initialisation file?

Comment: do you have empty schema at the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK `baselineOnMigrate` creates first (V1) version from your actual schema in DB. And only following version will get applied (V1.1, V2, ...).

So either don't use `baselineOnMigrate` but you need to start with empty DB schema or start indexing your versions from (eg.) V2.

Comment: ok thanks, that was a nice and easy fix. I just renamed the file to V2. cheers.